# How can I upgrade NPM on AWS Beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

AWS Beanstalk's Node.js configuration uses an outdated version of NPM and it's resulting in several bugs that I know have been fixed in later versions of NPM.

How can I simply update NPM on Beanstalk?

Answer (score 1):

Step to upgrade Node.js and NPM on AWS EBS

1. Open the [Elastic Beanstalk console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk).
2. Select the applications you want to upgrade
3. In the 'Overview Panel' you will find the change config button.

[image: As on date of Answer]

4. Select the latest platform you wish to deploy and click on save.
   [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm frustrated how this answer's got downvoted but it's hinted me how to upgrade/downgrade the node.js and npm versions (I wanted node v8.4.0/npm v5.3.0). The only limitation is that it would fail to change the platform when there's no the same node version as current one in desired platform. So I had to first downgrade node version in the current configuration to the one included in desired platform, switched the platform, and then finally change the node version to the version i wanted. Most important is that it worked within the beanstalk configurations without hack or something like that!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I modified my ebs configuration file (`.ebextensions`) adding the following to upgrade the current version of NPM.

Although the location of node will change depending on the image you are running, so you might have to change `opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.12.6-linux-x64/bin/` to the approprate path.

```
commands:
01-updatenpmv3:
    command: PATH=$PATH:/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.12.6-linux-x64/bin/ && npm update -g npm
    cwd: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.12.6-linux-x64/bin/
```